# sticky navigation hides at top of the page

Tags: jquery, navigation, hide, sticky

I'm looking for a piece of script that hides my sticky navigation at the very top of my page. So at the end it should start being visible when you scroll down entering the site.

This is the site I'm building: http://kmnew.kadushimarketing.com/index.php

This is the script I'm currently using:

```
$(function() {

    // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

    // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top

        // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
        if (scroll_top > sticky_navigation_offset_top) { 
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0 });
        } else {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative' }); 
        }   
    };

    // run our function on load
    sticky_navigation();

    // and run it again every time you scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation();
    });

});
```

Comment: Instead of using `position: relative` why don't you just hide it?

Comment: It should not be hidden all the time. Only at the very top of the page.

Comment: Hide it and make a scroll event listener with jquery. There you analyze the scroll position and show/hide the navigation.

Comment: @Marcel isn't it at the top of the page when you set it to `position: relative`?

Comment: I was thinking to add something like this: `$(document).ready(function(){

 // hide #back-top first
 $("#sticky_navigation").hide();
 
 // fade in #back-top
 $(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
    $('#sticky_navigation').fadeIn();
   } else {
    $('#sticky_navigation').fadeOut();
   }
  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I changed the script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // hide #sticky_navigation first
    $("#sticky_navigation").hide();

    // fade in #sticky_navigation
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('#sticky_navigation').fadeIn();
            } else {
                $('#sticky_navigation').fadeOut();
            }
        });


    });

});
```

Then I also added position: fixed to my css.

Comment: However it might not work 100%... It shows very quickly on page load, then it disappears. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for. If scrolltop is bigger than your windowheight, show it and place it at top

```
$(function() {

    // grab the initial top offset of the navigation 
    var sticky_navigation_offset_top = $('#sticky_navigation').offset().top;

    // our function that decides weather the navigation bar should have "fixed" css position or not.
    var sticky_navigation = function(){
        var scroll_top = $(window).scrollTop(); // our current vertical position from the top
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();

        // if we've scrolled more than the navigation, change its position to fixed to stick to top, otherwise change it back to relative
        if (scroll_top > windowHeight) { 
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':0, 'display': 'block' });
        } else {
            $('#sticky_navigation').css({ 'position': 'relative', 'display': 'none' }); 
        }   
    };

    // run our function on load
    sticky_navigation();

    // and run it again every time you scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
         sticky_navigation();
    });

});
```

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't do anything different than the code I have.

Comment: well what are you trying to do?